# What exactly is d3 selecting?

Tags: d3.js

Here is some code. It has poorly named variables and is wrong. The original example had only circles so that is why circle is being selected but now it has groups. However this code works correctly at the moment. It draws squares and circles as i expect.

Using the console i see 'circle' is `Array[3]` yet I can't figure out what the elements are or their type. Since its startup how is it possible theres 3 since no svg elements have been created?

Anyways I was wondering what circle should really be called? Doing a select all on "g" seems to give me the same effect. I'm guessing selectAll is trying to do a select and has 0 elements but continue to works somehow or maybe selectAll actually returns svg but in that case why am i creating a new variable. Also i'm not exactly sure why the examples and i are doing data on that. Is circle actually returning an internal d3 object that i now set data on? Does it have anything to do with svg or dom? I'm just confused why i am selectAll and calling data on the selection.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<style>
</style>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>


(function() {

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', 900);

var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data([32, 57, 293]);

circle.enter()
.append("g")
.call(function(gs) {
    gs.append("rect").attr("width", 20).attr("height", 20).attr("x", String);
    gs.append("circle").attr("cy", 90).attr("cx", String).attr("r", Math.sqrt);
})
.attr('class', 'test');
circle.exit().remove()

})();

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`circle` currently holds three SVGGElements, or `"g"`s, each of which holds a circle and a rectangle which were *.append*-ed in your example.

From the MDN:

> The g element is a container used to group objects. Transformations applied to the g element are performed on all of its child elements. Attributes applied are inherited by child elements. In addition, it can be used to define complex objects that can later be referenced with the  element.

`selectAll("some-container")` will return either an element matching that name or will create a new one and return it. See https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-d3_selectAll

Try adding these on line 27 to see the x values of your circles:

```
alert("x1: " + d3.select(circle.selectAll("circle")[0][0]).attr("cx"));
alert("x2: " + d3.select(circle.selectAll("circle")[1][0]).attr("cx"));
alert("x3: " + d3.select(circle.selectAll("circle")[2][0]).attr("cx"));
```